# How do I rank values of Pandas row into separate dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, ranking

My Dataframe having `df.shape` (500,15) has different values between (-1,1).

`df.head()`

```
0            -0.2966                 -0.1140  ...   0.4699      0.1250
1            -0.3051                 -0.1157  ...   0.6686      0.3290
2            -0.2014                 -0.1427  ...   0.4758      0.4919
3            -0.2703                 -0.0928  ...   0.6004      0.2436
4            -0.3399                 -0.0964  ...   0.3777      0.4808
```

I want to create a seperate dataframe which gives rank of the column in that specific row.
For example, df_rank (seperate df) first row would be ranks with largest number in the row being ranked 1 and lowest being ranked 15, without changing position/sorting. Same for second row and so on.

```
df_rank

0    11    8....    3    7
1    12    8....    1    3
2    13    7....    2    4
3    11    6....    3    6
4    12    6....    2    7
```

So on for all 500 rows...

Comment: Can you edit your example so the input and output match?  It'll be easier for people to answer them if they're complete examples (even if they're smaller than your real dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
df = df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  4  3  1  2
1  4  3  1  2
2  4  3  2  1
3  4  3  1  2
4  4  3  2  1
```